# Google Apps Script - Requires offline access loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to programmatically make changes to a Google site using Google Apps Script. I've made the following simple test function:

```
function test(){
  var url = "https://sites.google.com/a/some-site-here";
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url);
  page.setHtmlContent("This site has been updated");
}
```

On the first execution of this function, I am asked to authorise the script to manage my sites.

On every execution subsequent to this, I am asked to authorise the script to have offline access, and it never executes.

What must I do to get past this?

Comment: This could be happening if cookies are disabled or are being cleared.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe following info has something to do with your problem: "A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. Apps Script cannot currently access or modify Sites made with this version, but script can still access classic Sites." ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app says )

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue using Chrome. I tried with Firefox and no longer had the issue. I guess Chrome isn't handling the oAuth part correctly.